# How to use a maven BOM for Spring in Gradle?

Tags: maven, spring-boot, gradle

I am converting POM to Gradle and one of the things I am stuck at is having dependency management in Gradle like the following that I have in POM:

```xml
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>Edgware.SR4</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Is there a way to have `Edgware.SR4` in Gradle as well?

I checked https://docs.gradle.org/4.6/release-notes.html#bom-import but that doesn't really tell me a way on how to utilize `Edgware.SR4` BOM.

---

#### UPDATE

I finally have my build.gradle as follows that seems to work:

```
plugins{
   id 'org.springframework.boot' version '1.5.8.RELEASE'
}

apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
dependencyManagement {
    imports {
       mavenBom 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:Edgware.SR4'
    }
}
```

This seems to be working fine but wondering if there is any flaw in this approach. Documentation available at https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/gradle-plugin/reference/html/ suggests to use `apply false` to begin with in

```
id 'org.springframework.boot' version '1.5.8.RELEASE'
```

I didn't do that and it worked fine. Wondering why it was suggested like that.

Comment: The documentation you've linked to isn't for Spring Boot 1.5 (right now, it's for 2.1 but that'll change due to `current` in the URL). With 1.5 there's no need to apply the dependency management plugin (it's always applied for you) and there's no need for `apply false` either.

Comment: Refer to [this page](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/platforms.html#sub:bom_import) - it has the sample of BOM import in Gradle.

Answer (score 9):

As of today, the latest versions of gradle have a built-in solution.

```
dependencies {
    implementation(platform("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:Edgware.SR4"))
}
```

Comment: Is this for POM or BOM?

Comment: @EatonEmmerich, pom and bom is different things. Pom is maven build file, bom is list of dependency versions

Comment: That wasn't my question. @Spliterash
I obviously know there is a difference, Question is what is being added as dependency via the code provided, as question obviously stated it wanted a BOM not a POM.
The provided example link is a POM object.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that you are using Spring Boot and, therefore, already have the Dependency Management Plugin applied, you can import Spring Cloud's bom by adding the following to your `build.gradle` file:

```
dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:Edgware.SR4'
    }
}
```

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/gradle-plugin/reference/html/ This says that gradle includes a bom if dependency management plugin is included based on the spring boot starter parent version. Would that version numbers of dependencies resolve differently then what gets resolved in a maven project where one specifies a version of spring boot starter parent and BOM like Edgeware etc ? I believe not but just wanted to get a clarity on it.

Comment: No. If you use the same versions of Spring Boot and Spring Cloud in the two cases, you should get the same dependency versions with both Maven and Gradle.

Comment: Can you check my updates and see if I did the right thing that worked for me ?

Comment: Also, do i really need to refer to Edgeware BOM in gradle to achieve the maven like versions of the dependencies ?

Comment: Yes. How else is Gradle going to know about the versions?